APS Data Management API - BIM360 currently does not support the creation of refs
I tried to attach an item/version to another, like in the tutorial:https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/create-attachment/
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.G95jkGVnRvGee7NYd21DSQ?version=2",
        "meta": {
            "extension": {
                "type": "auxiliary:autodesk.core:Attachment",
                "version": "1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}


My goal is to reference a dwg-file to another dwg-file as an XREF.
My response is:
        "status": "400",
        "code": "FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED",
        "detail": "BIM360 currently does not support the creation of refs."

Is this not supported?

Just as the error message details, creating refs is currently NOT supported for BIM 360 Docs, this function is available for Fusion 360 projects.
